What is the quantum mechanical root of causality?
Consider the following 3 premises.
Premise 1) Quantum mechanics has an inherent randomness.
Premise 2) Objects in the world appear to obey causality. For example, I can push a book on a table, and it most certainly will move -- there is nothing random about this.
Premise 3) Classical physics can be achieved by taking certain limits in quantum theory (e.g. $\hbar \rightarrow 0$).
My question is How does causal behavior emerge if quantum physics is governed by randomness?
In considering this question, one possibility that I have come up with is that interactions can be random, but local, which could look like causality.
However, I am not convinced by this line of thought and am curious is there are more compelling answers.

I think you might be more interested in determinism (the initial data uniquely determine what will happen next) than causality (causes precede effects). If so, then basically in classical situations, the quantum mechanical probability distribution becomes very sharply peaked around the classically expected outcome, so the probability of anything other than the classical answer occurring is zero to an excellent approximation.

If you are interested in learning more about that, one of the ways this is expressed in quantum theory is the Ehrenfest theorem.

Premise #3 contradicts what we know about quantum mechanics. Also, you do not need to look at quantum mechanics, in many other theories microscopic randomness leads to macroscopic predictability, for instance, in classical thermodynamics or even sociology.

"Random" is the mathematician's way of saying, "unknowable." IMO, the "unknowability" (that is, the randomness) of quantum theories is of a weak sort. Suppose an atom in an excited state emits a photon. Where will the photon go? Quantum theories don't say. I've never heard anyone talk about a proof that we cannot predict the path of the photon. I've only ever them say that quantum theories don't predict it. Maybe the fate of the photon is determined by some state variable(s) that we don't yet know about. Maybe not—maybe it really is random. Quantum theories, AFAIK,* simply do not say.

* I am not actually a physicist.

@SolomonSlow There are certain things in quantum physics that we've experimentally shown to be unpredictable, given certain assumptions! In particular, it has been shown repeatedly that local hidden-variable theories give the wrong description for nature.

Premise 3 is dubious

@DanDan面, You seem to be saying that certain experiments have failed to show any evidence for a deterministic universe and, that certain theories turned out to be failures. So, No evidence. I've got to admit, the complete lack of evidence that unicorns ever existed would discourage a lot of people (myself included) from wasting our lives hunting for it. But I'm saying, lack of evidence is not the same thing as proof. I'll stick with my assertion that the randomness of quantum theory is a weak sort of randomness.

@SolomonSlow If we accept locality, then experiments have shown the stronger fact that no hidden variable theories can exist. See Bell's theorem or the CHSH inequality. To paraphrase, these experiments have shown that if quantum mechanics is deterministic (i.e. there is a hidden variable theory), then the only way that's possible is if there's something strange and nonlocal going on.

Randomness and "eventually deterministic behavior" are not mutually exclusive philosophical concepts. I cannot predict whether a coin will be heads or tails and yet after 10,000 such flips the distribution of the flips will resemble a Gaussian. Sufficiently many random variables doing their thing eventually can lead to a deterministic melody. It is this emergent deterministic world that we have evolved to live in, understand, think about, and for which "causality" has any kind of meaning.

I don’t think there is a single satisfying answer to your reasonable question. And I think Andrew’s comments are excellent.
A general argument would be that the random effects tend to net out as the system under observation gets larger. In that manner, the net random effect is very small compared to the system as a whole. But it is still there at all times.
One thing to keep in mind is that ordering is not always a factor in quantum systems anyway. Quantum outcomes appear to be dependent on a future context.
Further, it is not clear that larger systems are truly deterministic. You’d be hard-pressed to say that human behavior is deterministic, and you’d be equally hard-pressed to describe weather systems as deterministic.  So I’m not sure if causality is really emergent. It’s simply looks that way in controlled experiments.

In classical physics a measurable quantity of an objects, such as its $x$ position, is described by a function $x(t)$ so that if you measure the $x$ position at time $t$ you get the answer $x(t)$.
In quantum physics a measurable quantity is described by a quantum observable $\hat{X}$ whose value at a particular time can be represented by a Hermitian operator. The possible outcomes of measurements are its eigenvalues $x_a$. Using another operator called the state, which is represented by a Hermitian operator $\rho$ with trace 1, quantum theory predicts the probability of each possible outcome $p_a$ and gives the expectation value of $\hat{X}$ as
$$
\langle\hat{X}\rangle=tr(\rho\hat{X})=\sum_ap_ax_a
$$
The state describes what observables have been measured and what their values were.
While these equations are uncontroversial there is a lot of controversy about how to understand them: this controversy is said to be about the interpretation of quantum theory with different explanations being called interpretations. Some interpretations, such as the Copenhagen and statistical interpretations say that you should just use these equations without expecting any explanation. This has the problem that if you can't explain whats happening in an experiment there is no standard by which to decide if you've set it up correctly.
Another interpretation, commonly called the many worlds interpretation, states that we should understand quantum theory by working out the consequences of its equations of motion as we would for any other theory. If we do that then in general the outcome of an experiment depends on what happens to all of the possible states of the system. This is called interference. For an example, see Section 2 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
In some sense the system is in all of the possible states during an interference experiment. This raises a problem: why don't you diffract when you walk through a doorway and why do you only see a single version of the objects around you.
If you copy information out of a quantum system interference is suppressed - an effect called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
The objects you see around you evolve much more slowly than the rate at which information is copied out of them by light reflecting off them, interactions with air, surfaces they rest on and that sort of thing. As a result interference is very effectively suppressed. As a result the different versions of those objects don't interfere and evolve autonomously from one another:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
Conservation laws tend to make observables for decoherent systems obey the equations of motion of classical physics to a very good approximation because they result in strong correlations between decoherent observables along classical trajectories:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1802
So the answer to why systems behave in an approximately deterministic fashion in everyday life is decoherence and conservation laws.

The state of a particle is described by its wave function. The Schrodinger equation governs the evolution of the state. If you know the wave function now, the Schrodinger equation tells you the wave function in the future.
If you measure the position of the particle, there is some randomness. The value of the wave function at a given position tells you the probability density of finding the particle there. The Schrodinger equation governs how the probabilities evolve with time.
The way the particle interacts with the rest of the universe is described by the potential. The potential appears in the Schrodinger equation. It affects the solution.
For example in one common problem, the particle is an electron and the rest of the universe consists of a proton. The attractive force of the proton causes the electron to have a lower potential energy when near the nucleus.
If the electron has a low energy, the solution to the Schrodinger is a set of orbitals. These are wave functions that do not change with time. If the wave function starts out in one of these states, it stays in that state. The electron is bound to the nucleus. The Schrodinger equation for this potential tells the size and shape of the orbitals.

But how does classical determinism fall out of this description?

The Schrodinger equation describes the evolution "between measurements". It doesn't explain what measurement is.

Reality has a causal structure: "Future" events cannot influence "past" events, where "future" and "past" are to be understood relativistically as the "past" event being outside the light cone of the "future" event.
But this does not imply determinism, as Andrew remarked correctly. The underlying quantum randomness and indeterminism of reality implies "future" realities that are not perfectly known. This "error bar" widens with time and influences increasingly large collectives of matter: While some volume of air's movement in a weather pattern becomes quickly unpredictable, the planets'1, let alone the galaxies' movements do not. And yet, gravitational systems with more than two bodies are inherently unstable so that even microscopic indeterminisms eventually grow to macroscopic proportions: A planet may be ejected from its system or not; a meteorite may hit Earth or miss it. The dinosaurs may live or, instead, funny furry critters who nurse their offspring whose descendants eventually start reasoning about the underlying nature of reality ...

1 It should be noted that the planets' movements in our Solar system are predictable and stable because unstable states, tautologically, tend to change, while more stable ones tend to stay. The Solar system was originally much more unstable. For example, early in the history of the Solar system, the Earth probably collided with another planet, an event which formed the Moon. Such intersecting, unstable  orbits were of course much harder to predict, but they have been weeded out. What stayed are stable orbits with fairly good predictability (for cosmologically near futures).
